# Prevent videos watched in youtube embedded player from appearing in user watch history

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am showing unlisted videos uploaded on youtube studio in youtube embedded player on my website. I  have disabled sharing the video and youtube button on the video is not clickable. This is because I want users to watch the video only on my website.
But after user watches the video on my website on youtube embedded player, the video appears in users watch history on youtube.com. I want to avoid that.
Is there a way to do that ?

I tried looking into options in youtube embedded player to disable video from appearing in watch history. But I could not find any such option.

Comment: Add the code of the iframe/embed you're using. I tried by watching a video embed on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcj50yfu/) - [credits to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77827641/4092887) - and, even when I'm logged with my YouTube account, this video does not appeared on my watch list. It *might* be because it's an auto-generated video or because it has their comments option disabled...[edit] your question and add what have you tried.